# SQL Server Reporting Services using of pictures with dynamic links

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have setup a SSRS 2008 and building reports. So far so good.
Now there is a picture control in SSRS where you can set the picture as external link reference.

There you can choose to use a link. When I use a weblink (http://anyurl/download_picture.aspx?id=123) it dont' work for me. 
Calling the url in the web browser (all tested IE, Safari, Chrome, FF) the pictures is delivered, Header is ok, content type, too.

Does it work in general in SSRS ? Or do I have to copy the picture to a temp folder and link the url like http://anyurl/mypicture.jpg.

Comment: When you preview the report in BIDS, are you getting any errors or warnings? (check the Error List window as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using external images required additional configuration.  Have a look here on how to configure the Unattended Execution Account: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx

> Retrieve external image files that are
>   used in report. If you want to use an
>   image file and the file cannot be
>   accessed through Anonymous access, you
>   can configure the unattended report
>   processing account and grant the
>   account permission to access the file.

Comment: Unfortunetaley dynamic links are not able to be used in reports. External URL links seems to work with the setup of the account you mentioned, but using dynamicpic.aspx?id=123 don't work, the report won't process it, big BS :s Anyway, thx for the help, seems MS screwed up it again...

Comment: I don't see why dynamic links wouldn't work, as long as the link is an actual, correct and working link. Should start with "http://" for instance. To debug, try to output it in a textbox on your report, then copy that link into your browser and see if it works...

Comment: the link works in the browser, that I made sure. But the download site page copy the image from an not accessable store to a public store and then response redirect to the picture. So maybe that is the case. I will try to make a direct picture stream instead and see if this works.